# What env variable should does node use to load libraries?

Tags: node.js, linux, path

I am getting this error on server:

node: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

however a simple find shows:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I already have the following set in .bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin:/usr/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:~/.local/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:~/.local/lib
```

yet node can't find the existing libstd library. 
I have done

```
source .bashrc
```

and also

```
echo $LIBRARY_PATH
```

This is a really common problem I searched, but most solutions recommended an install in my case the file is installed node just doesn't see it.

Comment: Whats your OS ?

Comment: How did you installed node? Try setting `LD_DEBUG`.

Comment: that was all I needed unfortunately I am know getting a new error with the install. make set LB_DEBUG an answer and I can mark it as correct. thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing missing `lib32stdc++` by `apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

Set `LD_DEBUG` for better diagnose.
If the `LD_DEBUG` variable is set then the Linux dynamic linker will dump debug information which can be used to resolve most loading problems very quickly. To see the available options just run any program with the variable set to help.

Valid options for the LD_DEBUG environment variable are:

```
  libs        display library search paths
  reloc       display relocation processing
  files       display progress for input file
  symbols     display symbol table processing
  bindings    display information about symbol binding
  versions    display version dependencies
  all         all previous options combined
  statistics  display relocation statistics
  unused      determined unused DSOs
  help        display this help message and exit
```

Comment: this was nice but if you read the original post you would have noticed the file is installed. Also I am on a server not a local computer so I can not use apt-get. I need the 32-bit versios of the library locally. anyways good answer.